# How to create interactive window in Paraview from Python script?

Tags: python, paraview

I am just starting to learn Paraview and how to interact with it from a Python script (executed in IPython). The [tutorial](http://www.paraview.org/ParaView3/Doc/Nightly/www/py-doc/quick-start.html) shows how to create a view and render it. Example:

```
from paraview.simple import *
Cone()
Show()
Render()
```

The resulting window is non-interactive though. **How can I enable basic mouse interactions like rotation and zoom?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an old post in paraview mailing list that says it's not possible: (http://www.paraview.org/pipermail/paraview/2007-June/005230.html)

> On Thu, 14 Jun 2007 Utkarsh Ayachit wrote :
>   Currently, the render window cannot be made interactive through 
>   pvpython. To get an interactor to work in ParaView, there's some 
>   additional meat that needs to be implemented by the GUI layer. The 
>   python API does not provide for that.

I don't know if there have been updates in the meanwhile

Comment: There hasn't been any update on this yet. It's on the todo list, but a lower priority :).

Answer (score 3):

Appears that it should be possible through the function

```
paraview.simple.Interact(view=None)
```

in the most recent version. See http://www.paraview.org/ParaView3/Doc/Nightly/www/py-doc/paraview.simple.html#paraview.simple.Interact

Answer (score 1):

**pvbatch** doesn't support interaction.

But you can interact with these views in **pvpython**.
Just like this:

```py
from paraview.simple import *
Cone()
Show()
Render()
Interact()
```

See [Interacting with views in ParaView Python (pvpython)](https://blog.kitware.com/interacting-with-views-in-paraview-python-pvpython/)